# How to open url in a new tab in Django?

Tags: python, django, browser, hyperlink, browser-tab

I have to open the result page using render_to_response on a new tab.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Django is server-side, opening in a new tab is client-side. So use an `<A>` with a `target="_blank"`

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=target%3Dblank

But of course spawning new windows/tabs is annoying for the user, so try not to do that after all.

Comment: thanks , but my control is in views.py i want the control to transferred to a new page and it must open in new tab.

Comment: It has to be done in the template that gets written out, in the HTML.

Comment: Not exactly: you could code a middleware that will change your html, search for A tags and add the target="_blank".

Comment: Thanks for making the server/client side distinction. It all makes sense now

Comment: Also, don't forget to use `noopener` like this: `<a href="http://example" target="_blank" rel="noopener">`, as it's a security vulnerability if you forget.

Comment: [more about "noopener"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/noopener)

Answer (score 9):

Most the time, loading the page in a new tab can be a real pain in the ar** for the user. Nevertheless it can still be necessary sometimes. If you really need to render your POST results in a new tab, use the `target="_blank"` as an attribute of your `<form>`.

Comment: Also, don't forget to use `noopener` like this: `<a href="http://example" target="_blank" rel="noopener">`, as it's a security vulnerability if you forget.

Comment: [more about "noopener"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/noopener)

Answer (score 0):

this was problem when i was passing the dynamic URL in DTL. i also solved by putting the target="_blank" after the href closed.

```
      <h3 class="card-title">
                        <i class="fas fa-bell fa-2x mr-1"></i>
                        <a href="{% url 'alerts' site=data.site.name  %}  " target ="_blank">Notifications </i></a>
                     </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a></a>` with `target="_blank"` below can open url in a new tab:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

And, `<a></a>` without `target="_blank"` below can open url in the current tab:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```