# Redirect/Render many pages in DJANGO at once

Tags: python, django

I write a project in django.
I've got data from MS SQL called orders - there are few rows from the table.
I would like to loop it, and each of them should render new tab '/print' with some context **in order to create and download pdf**.
Like:

```
for o in orders:
    HttpResponseRedirect('/print')
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415600/how-to-open-url-in-new-tab-from-django). You can't do that from the server-side of the application.

Comment: consider evil-app which opens 500000 tabs in your webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

Don't you only have 1 page to edit all the elements? Then you could perhaps hardcode the link e.g.:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(my_edit_url)
```

If this doesn't work and you need to go 2 pages back take a look at this post: How to redirect to previous page in Django after POST request